# Do I need to keep an SSH session alive for cron to run?

Tags: ssh, cron

I know about `nohup`. It prevents processes from dying after a hang-up.

What I want is my user crontabs to run even if my session has timed out when they are supposed to run. I believe I need the user to be still logged on for that to happen.

How do I make sure that the user's crontab are run whatever if he's logged on or not?

Do I need to make the user actually is logged on?

Should I use a system crontab instead?

Any other solutions?

Comment: "I believe I need the user to be still logged on for that to happen." Cron executes even if you're not logged in. It also runs outside of any login session you have going. Not sure what you mean by the "system" crontab. If it's the crontab you get from "root" then that's just another user's crontab. That user just happens to also be root.

Comment: The user does not need to be logged on for `cron` to run that user's jobs.

Comment: @Bratchley: "system crontab", I meant `/etc/cron*`. I am not sure how they relate to the `/var/spool/cron/...`, or which files `crontab -e` actually edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[cron](/questions/tagged/cron) runs whether you are logged-in or not.

It's a daemon that checks items in the `crontab` (cron table) and runs them at the appointed time(s).

If you had to be logged-in to do it, it would be pretty unhelpful - more like running a process in the background after a `sleep`, or in a loop.

Comment: Well, it could still help, for example if you want to launch some kind of sync every 5 minutes. Of course I agree that it is much more powerful like this. If there are hundreds of users on a machine, then all of their crontabs would run? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Gauthier - yep: if `cron` is enabled for the user, they can have a `crontab`. Of course, they may be restricted on what they can schedule.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't have to be logged in to run tasks in cron. Its whole idea is to keep track of scheduled tasks without any need of user interaction. You just set up a crontab and forget about it, no hassle with logging in is needed.

Additional tip: you can run programs in the background easily by launching `<command> &` or, if for some reason you prefer or need to run something in the foreground, you can use `screen` or `tmux` to keep your session alive even after you disconnect from the server.

Comment: Ouch. I understand that knowing this little about crontabs makes me look like a total newbie, but your additional tips kind of hurt ;) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, absolutely no offence meant ;)